# left vs translateX in CSS3 Animations

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, css-transitions

I have created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5sZ9y/3/); The red box animates with CSS `left` property, and the blue one animates with CSS Transform `TranslateX` property.

In Chrome 21, Both animations have the same performace, both running smoothly.

But in Safari (for Windows), the blue one animates smoothly, but the red one is laggy. (Seems that the blue one is hardware-accelerated, while the red one not)

The first question is, What is the best choice? Which one is better at overall? (support by more browsers, etc.)

And next, Isn't there any way to Hardware-accelerate animations on `left` and `top` CSS properties in Safari? (Since I want to actually move a `div` to outside of window, I think using `left` property is better.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translate is there to move objects around without affecting there position in the DOM. Although it visibly moves to another place on the screen the DOM is not affect. This is why the performance of the translate function generally is better.

Be warned that you will not see the same performance characteristics in every browser.

This is a JSPerf overview of the different [translate/move](http://jsperf.com/translate3d-vs-xy/5) functions. Scroll to the bottom to see the statistics per browser.

It will most likely change in the future.

Comment: So, If I want to move something to outside of window, I should first animate it using `TranslateX`, and after a while, move it actually to outside (with `left` property) with no animation using `setTimeout`. Right?

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi Do you still need it in the DOM after it moves off screen? Otherwise you can remove it. Or keep it out of view and don't change anything in the DOM.

Comment: Yes, I need it after moving off screen. I'm creating something like a carousel, which slides some `div`s. So, you think that the method that I said in my previous comment, is the best way?

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi If translate does what you want I wouldn't touch any other css property (from a performance standpoint). Do you also need to support older browsers? If yes I would develop something that uses translate if it is there, otherwise fallback to using the left property.

Comment: The tool that you linked, says css left/top is fastest in even Safari. But It is not true, at least for CSS3 animations...

Comment: So, If I don't need to support older browsers, I should **not** use `left` property for animations at all?

Comment: I would try both solutions and see which works best for the browsers you need to support. My expectation is that translate will go faster when time goes on. Also add -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); to enable hardware acceleration in Chrome and mobile devices.

Comment: And why translate **Z** is necessary for enabling hardware acceleration?